# MYSQL - Subquery on same table in WHERE clause of UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql

I got an ***"error '#1093 - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause"*** with this code:

```
UPDATE `table1` t1 SET t1.name = 'abc'
WHERE t1.id = 165 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT t2.id FROM `table1` t2 WHERE t2.id != 165 AND t2.name = 'abc'    
)
```

But there is no problem with the code:

```
UPDATE `table1` t1 SET t1.name = 'abc'
WHERE t1.id = 165 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT t2.id FROM `table2` t2 WHERE t2.id != 165 AND t2.name = 'abc'    
)
```

What did I go wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve MySQL error "You can't specify target table X for update in FROM clause"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251621/how-to-resolve-mysql-error-you-cant-specify-target-table-x-for-update-in-from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rephrase this query as a self join to the same table:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
    ON t2.id != 165 AND t2.name = 'abc'
SET t1.name = 'abc'
WHERE t1.id = 165 AND t2.name IS NULL
```

The update logic here is that your `NOT EXISTS` clause has been replaced with a `LEFT JOIN` where any record from the left side of the join did *not* match (`t2.name IS NULL`) to any record where the `id` is not 165 and the name is `abc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same, without using inner query:

```
UPDATE `table1` t1 SET t1.name = 'abc'
WHERE t1.id = 165 AND t1.name != 'abc'
```

Comment: It is different from what I want to get